# Typescript: default value of function parameter missing required properties

Tags: typescript

```
interface IPrintConfig {
    name: string;
    copies: number;
}

function print(config: IPrintConfig = {}) {
    console.log(`Print ${config.copies} on printer ${config.name}`);
}

print();
```

[image]

when nothing it passed to `print()` i made the default value as `{}`. But `print()` is expecting a value of type `IPrintConfig` which comntains `name` and `copies` properties. I can solve this issue by making both of those properties as optional. Is there another way to solve this issue without making them optional

Comment: What values do you want `config.copies` and `config.name` to have inside the implementation if someone just calls `print()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1

Make your interface values optional using a `?`:

```
interface IPrintConfig {
    name?: string;
    copies?: number;
}

function print(config: IPrintConfig = {}) {
    console.log(`Print ${config.copies} on printer ${config.name}`);
}
```

### Option 2

Make the parameter optional instead of predefined:

```
function print(config?: IPrintConfig) {
  if(config)
    console.log(`Print ${config.copies} on printer ${config.name}`);
  else
    console.log(`No value passed`);
}
```

### Option 3

Set the default values:

```
function print(config: IPrintConfig = {name: '', copies: -1}) {
    console.log(`Print ${config.copies} on printer ${config.name}`);
}
```

### Option 4

Require that the parameter be passed to the function:

```
function print(config: IPrintConfig) {
    console.log(`Print ${config.copies} on printer ${config.name}`);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you wouldn't assign a default value.

Answer (score 0):

What if you make param optional?

```
interface IPrintConfig {
    name: string;
    copies: number;
}

function print(config?: IPrintConfig) {
    config  && console.log(`Print ${config.copies} on printer ${config.name}`);
}

print();
```

Comment: What do you intend `config?.properties` to mean?  That's not valid TypeScript or JavaScript syntax, as far as I know

Comment: Indeed it is a valid operator in TypeScript, and called optional chaining

Comment: [I don't think so](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUqjAYQPYgzADmyA3gFDLXIhwC2EAXMgM5hYjEDcVNCeAA7AIrFiACu9AEbReAXwoUYEkAjDACyQZzAAKAYRIB+Fhl34jxAJTk+1Q6zwAbCADpneYnoAGmbMgAJGSGRMTGbgLCovLIWjrY0EEhBGERdIzyPta8NMgA9Pl5xXkAogBK5QDy5cgAtA0NAHzIAH4lNBXVtY29vS2tFIoUCeB6OUA)

Comment: The exclamation point is valid though `config!.properties` might mean something different though

Comment: `config!.properties` will throw a runtime exception if `config` is not defined, so you don't want to do that.

Comment: `config?.properties` just [isn't valid TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16) because it [isn't yet valid JavaScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining); it's a stage 2 proposal.  One day, yes, maybe.  Now, no.

Comment: @jcalz my bad, mixed up with `!`

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly that's a [runtime error](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUqjAYQPYgzADmyA3gFDLXIhwC2EAXMgM5hYjEDcVNCeAA7AIrFiACu9AEbReAXwoUYEkAjDACyQZzAAKAYRIB+Fhl34jxAJTk+1Q6zwAbCADpneYnoAGmbMgAJGSGRMQAhG4CwqLyyFo62NBBIQRhkXSM8j7WCkqJ4Hq5yAD0JcgASgCqAHIAKqgAsgCiyM0VFQDyFch1AJ6CEM1QUHhQLKEkyMCsyKoAJhBEIBDzQA) so you don't want to suggest that either.